# Shapely Not Determining Point in State

Tags: shapefile, shapely, geoalchemy

I am pulling State geometry data from a database (populated from Shapefiles) to find what state a coordinate pair is in.  I was originally using [GeoAlchemy](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.6/), but tens of thousands of queries to determine the state is quite expensive.

```
def get_state_from_coordinates(self, db_session, long, lat):
    return db_session.query(States)\
        .filter(func.ST_Contains(States.geom, func.ST_PointFromText('POINT({0} {1})'.format(long, lat), 4269)))\
        .first()
```

So my current solution is to pull all of the state data into my application and do the lookup locally.  I wanted to spike out a lookup and have gotten stuck.

```
states = db_session.query(States).all()

for state in states:
    point = Point(-81.4406293, 30.323164199999997)
    if state.geom is not None:    
        poly = to_shape(state.geom)
        if point.within(poly):
            print('Point is in {0}'.format(state.name))
```

This *should* print `Point is in Florida` but the point is never found in the `poly`.  For those curious, after transforming the `geom` from the DB to a Shapely poly here are the `poly.geoms`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1T1VYM2f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is shapely. Using the data from your pastebin, and a simple test:

```
>>> import shapely
>>> from shapely.wkt import loads
>>> state = loads('POLYGON ((-80.7856622716253 28.78519435427305, -80.76241527160364 28.73633435422754, -80.83210427166854 28.78618635427397, -80.85070527168587 28.78570035427352, -80.74719027158946 28.39899235391336, -80.49224427135204 27.87017835342087, -80.50935827136797 27.82570835337945, -80.48185327134235 27.84572135339809, -80.40137727126741 27.70358535326572, -80.35737827122642 27.55566235312795, -80.23963827111677 27.26464735285693, -80.19009127107063 27.18568435278338, -80.2239892711022 27.21506635281075, -80.28963527116333 27.24133835283521, -80.32679127119793 27.24826235284166, -80.29042027116407 27.21285335280869, -80.22127327109966 27.20284235279937, -80.14796727103139 27.10906935271203, -80.09036327097775 26.97404335258628, -80.11461027100033 26.97383735258609, -80.050911270941 26.79719735242158, -80.08469527097247 26.32637735198309, -80.12778127101259 25.97753635165821, -80.19309927107342 25.76003235145564, -80.30145627117435 25.61375135131941, -80.32999127120092 25.49001535120417, -80.30197527117483 25.40120035112145, -80.41681627128177 25.24990235098054, -80.4208072712855 25.19221935092682, -80.55187627140756 25.21231835094554, -80.69382527153977 25.15229935088965, -80.85680127169155 25.18563135092069, -80.97587727180245 25.13050135086934, -81.11901627193575 25.13418835087278, -81.14823027196296 25.16469035090119, -81.18378427199607 25.26887935099822, -81.14056927195583 25.32076535104654, -81.01156027183568 25.21442935094751, -80.95102727177931 25.20253735093643, -80.915274271746 25.24672535097759, -80.97428127180096 25.32246035104812, -81.14332327195839 25.39682735111738, -81.25837527206555 25.68110035138213, -81.19994727201113 25.71042235140944, -81.25620727206352 25.80310235149575, -81.5307422723192 25.91465835159965, -81.71829327249388 25.92358135160796, -81.70569527248215 26.00017235167929, -81.79471727256505 26.11116235178266, -81.81385827258288 26.28446735194406, -81.84935127261593 26.33219735198851, -81.86421227262977 26.4395543520885, -81.94201827270224 26.46756235211458, -81.96811927272654 26.51738235216098, -81.9287732726899 26.53498035217737, -81.88427627264846 26.64298735227796, -81.77391427254568 26.71026535234061, -81.8971022726604 26.66376735229731, -81.9444522727045 26.55071935219203, -82.02147327277623 26.52468035216778, -82.08366027283415 26.71579035234576, -82.06827127281981 26.76697035239343, -82.05176727280445 26.86670935248631, -82.09787227284738 26.92178535253761, -81.99144027274826 26.96305635257605, -81.97919427273686 27.03168035263996, -81.99285127274958 27.03167635263995, -82.01268827276805 26.97655035258861, -82.15321027289892 26.93706535255184, -82.25745927299602 27.00440935261456, -82.28217927301904 27.02455735263332, -82.25758227299613 26.9979073526085, -82.1764952729206 26.91369335253007, -82.1538282728995 26.79012835241499, -82.28984027302617 26.84988635247065, -82.35543127308726 26.94889635256285, -82.39817127312706 26.99851535260907, -82.36866827309959 26.94793835256197, -82.34362827307626 26.9036323525207, -82.38003627311018 26.94729635256137, -82.50693027322835 27.23699135283117, -82.53113127325089 27.26027735285285, -82.51448327323538 27.21045335280645, -82.56995727328705 27.27428035286589, -82.53274027325239 27.33180235291947, -82.56556227328295 27.38668135297058, -82.68592527339506 27.47384435305175, -82.63888927335125 27.50345935307934, -82.66582927337633 27.49358735307014, -82.68170627339113 27.52442935309887, -82.48826727321097 27.47806735305569, -82.51419927323512 27.51198935308728, -82.42717727315407 27.5228593530974, -82.57557127329228 27.51232435308759, -82.63876727335114 27.53663835311023, -82.56960527328673 27.55271335312521, -82.55426227327243 27.5822393531527, -82.62637627333959 27.55519435312752, -82.54004127325919 27.60810635317679, -82.55250027327079 27.64401435321024, -82.40437927313285 27.79162835334771, -82.39881727312766 27.90621935345443, -82.46099827318557 27.94015535348604, -82.48313127320618 27.82194735337595, -82.51059827323176 27.8312323533846, -82.53899527325821 27.93572835348192, -82.64556527335746 28.02884735356864, -82.65068427336223 28.00716335354845, -82.69833927340662 28.04616935358477, -82.67271927338275 28.01051435355156, -82.70066627340879 27.97535335351882, -82.6447412733567 27.96658435351065, -82.7254852734319 27.94056235348642, -82.56426427328175 27.87846235342858, -82.62365327333706 27.8485273534007, -82.64461927335658 27.71572535327702, -82.67832627338798 27.70558735326758, -82.79383827349555 27.82965435338313, -82.72816327343439 27.71777335327893, -82.74100327344635 27.68586835324922, -82.84428527354254 27.85064135340267, -82.77914427348188 28.17302735370292, -82.67347627338346 28.42851035394086, -82.63607527334862 28.69274935418695, -82.68138027339081 28.80838235429464, -82.63651927334904 28.81427835430013, -82.63661927334914 28.88470835436572, -82.75532227345968 29.00866035448116, -82.8021572735033 29.15513235461757, -83.03674727372179 29.17938735464016, -83.07392827375641 29.2656523547205, -83.14220627381999 29.29965135475217, -83.10899527378906 29.32818235477874, -83.1746332738502 29.34367935479317, -83.23432827390579 29.43393735487723, -83.38003127404149 29.51987435495727, -83.40497427406471 29.66960235509671, -83.55044827420021 29.73732335515978, -83.65418227429682 29.9109613553215, -83.97173827459255 30.07748335547658, -84.07462527468839 30.0999483554975, -84.14785527475658 30.08172535548053, -84.23307127483595 30.10811135550511, -84.35392527494849 30.06962435546926, -84.36041627495455 29.97739035538336, -84.43769027502651 29.99179135539677, -84.43310427502225 29.95954535536674, -84.33893827493455 29.94714135535519, -84.34691127494197 29.91016835532076, -84.46453827505151 29.92962735533888, -84.85803027541799 29.74686035516866, -84.92851327548362 29.77797235519764, -84.98828327553929 29.71992135514358, -85.21476027575021 29.70155735512648, -85.36487927589002 29.68301935510921, -85.40960427593167 29.77676635519651, -85.41405227593582 29.86306735527689, -85.39299427591621 29.87541335528839, -85.4025462759251 29.79436535521291, -85.35804327588366 29.69125435511688, -85.30658927583573 29.70171035512661, -85.30052427583009 29.80979635522728, -85.38479227590857 29.92380135533345, -85.62849727613553 30.09259135549065, -85.56852827607969 30.09829335549596, -85.47135827598919 30.02186335542478, -85.41501327593672 30.0315523554338, -85.43238627595289 30.04575435544703, -85.38269427590662 30.02427035542702, -85.38265627590658 30.03628635543821, -85.3956722759187 30.05856735545896, -85.46431627598263 30.05116335545207, -85.52971627604354 30.13168635552706, -85.70982927621128 30.17877335557091, -85.66605827617052 30.25168935563882, -85.60017627610917 30.25115135563832, -85.56947527608057 30.31100435569407, -85.71713127621808 30.26506235565128, -85.75270827625121 30.29692935568096, -85.85042027634222 30.28035935566552, -85.82994227632315 30.23281435562124, -85.75791927625608 30.22894535561764, -85.72639327622672 30.12884235552441, -85.98701327646943 30.27443035566, -86.38745927684238 30.38765935576546, -86.50531427695213 30.40997335578624, -86.38810827684298 30.40601235578255, -86.24003327670508 30.39988735577684, -86.24156627670651 30.42852735580352, -86.11464027658829 30.38580235576373, -86.12293427659601 30.42646135580159, -86.21960827668605 30.48785435585877, -86.38787927684277 30.46216735583485, -86.45263927690308 30.50123735587123, -86.61023627704985 30.42365135579897, -86.79034727721759 30.41796335579368, -87.19338227759295 30.35522135573525, -86.93251127734999 30.46356535583615, -87.01440027742626 30.51443435588352, -86.98619327739999 30.5904303559543, -87.01958027743109 30.58746635595154, -87.06927227747737 30.45056435582404, -87.12453327752883 30.56466635593031, -87.17155527757262 30.55773535592385, -87.16010227756196 30.46503335583752, -87.27389727766794 30.35738435573726, -87.4240802778078 30.32367135570586, -87.409256277794 30.40223935577903, -87.34680727773583 30.43149835580628, -87.34739527773638 30.45716935583019, -87.4188162778029 30.48170035585304, -87.44535327782762 30.53138935589931, -87.42206727780592 30.55649335592269, -87.39328127777912 30.62009835598193, -87.39864527778411 30.66801535602656, -87.41889427780298 30.69281035604965, -87.46014027784139 30.70580235606175, -87.52660327790329 30.74849135610151, -87.54190027791753 30.78569535613616, -87.61591527798646 30.84829635619446, -87.62571127799559 30.8769023562211, -87.5898672779622 30.95436135629324, -87.59858027797031 31.00263035633819, -87.16311727756477 31.00315735633868, -86.77936127720736 30.99819135633406, -86.70185227713517 30.99809235633396, -86.38391927683908 30.99153835632786, -86.18147627665054 30.9952253563313, -86.03182227651116 30.99332735632953, -85.48659727600338 31.00099835633667, -85.4850102760019 31.00100135633667, -85.00160727555171 31.00125335633691, -85.00014227555033 30.97931935631648, -84.97356727552558 30.9636643563019, -84.96901227552135 30.92709335626784, -84.93777627549225 30.89495735623791, -84.92692627548215 30.84692235619318, -84.93256427548739 30.80262535615192, -84.92689527548212 30.77608835612721, -84.91534327547136 30.75408935610672, -84.88828927544617 30.74388935609722, -84.86458327542408 30.71450335606986, -84.86300327542261 30.71266435606814, -84.37444827496762 30.69409235605085, -84.2816632748812 30.69041935604742, -84.07556227468925 30.67857735603639, -84.00073027461956 30.67553735603356, -83.73784427437472 30.66049135601955, -83.60905627425478 30.65078435601051, -83.31060027397683 30.63430335599516, -83.30131527396819 30.63328535599421, -83.1324402738109 30.62134135598309, -82.69635627340477 30.59572035595923, -82.58295727329916 30.58905335595302, -82.46313527318756 30.58268935594709, -82.41209227314003 30.57730735594208, -82.22103927296209 30.56707635593255, -82.23839627297826 30.53144435589937, -82.21936727296054 30.50297035587285, -82.19918727294174 30.49001435586078, -82.20556527294768 30.42385335579916, -82.1802342729241 30.36863135574773, -82.16463927290957 30.3612913557409, -82.05276727280538 30.36379435574323, -82.03835427279195 30.3789043557573, -82.04609927279917 30.43406835580868, -82.03512027278894 30.44287835581688, -82.0225092727772 30.47771735584933, -82.00580127276164 30.5709903559362, -82.01365227276895 30.59869035596199, -82.04491127279806 30.65091035601063, -82.03188127278592 30.75753235610993, -82.01296727276831 30.76425635611619, -82.01553827277071 30.79131935614139, -81.98148027273899 30.77835135612931, -81.96155127272043 30.79600735614576, -81.95302927271248 30.82043135616851, -81.9438052727039 30.82424935617206, -81.9075182726701 30.81347535616203, -81.89914127266231 30.82830835617584, -81.87300227263796 30.79908435614863, -81.80319827257296 30.78808535613838, -81.77670827254828 30.7615843561137, -81.75771027253059 30.7696313561212, -81.73667527251099 30.76388835611585, -81.71676927249246 30.7453693560986, -81.64247727242326 30.72908135608343, -81.62798127240977 30.73177435608594, -81.60477127238815 30.71632135607155, -81.60117027238479 30.72488735607952, -81.53659127232466 30.70657735606247, -81.5285952723172 30.72145235607633, -81.49878427228944 30.59860535596192, -81.51811727230745 30.55621235592243, -81.45752827225103 30.45476435582795, -81.48079827227269 30.38054035575882, -81.44326027223774 30.35718735573708, -81.43276727222796 30.24678135563425, -81.30275827210689 29.91305235532344, -81.31649027211967 29.82924035524539, -81.24378427205195 29.73794335516036, -81.23376627204263 29.66902435509618, -81.10988027192725 29.43023935487379, -81.0970542719153 29.35179935480074, -80.7856622716253 28.78519435427305))')
>>> testpoint = loads('POINT(-81.4406293 30.323164199999997)')
>>> if testpoint.within(state):
...    print "inside state"
... 
inside state
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks in a big way to @BradHands for pointing out that my suspicions that it was Shapely were incorrect.  I noticed that the `geom` from Shapely was a `POLYGON` and in my SQLAlchemy model it was defined as `MULTIPOLYGON`.

```
class States(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'states'

    state_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    abbreviation = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    geom = Column(Geography(geometry_type='MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4269))
```

Once I switched the `States.geom` definition to `geometry_type='POLYGON'` my script worked.  So my model now looks like this:

```
class States(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'states'

    state_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    abbreviation = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    geom = Column(Geography(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid=4269))
```

Comment: So the key outcome is providing all the information in the question...